# keras v. tf.keras compile command for sequential model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I've been getting up to speed in keras, not realizing that tf.keras is also a thing (and for newbies, it's easy to get cross ways with imports in python). In trying to convert a script from keras to tf.keras, it appears that the commands are not consistent? In general, is tf.keras supposed to follow the keras documentation, or are they diverging?

My specific issue is that this works with keras, but not tf.keras:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This gives error:

```
ValueError: optimizer must be an instance of tf.train.Optimizer, not a <class 'str'>
```

This seems inconsistent with the tf.keras docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model#compile).  Any idea what is going on?

Comment: How do you define your model? Add full code please

Comment: Please provide the minimal code and the version of TensorFlow.

Comment: While in the process of putting together a minimal code example for keras and tf.keras, I came across the difference, which is that I had eager execution enabled for the failing case in tf.keras.  With this disabled, it works as expected.  I will put in a short answer to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the error is a result of having tensorflow eager execution enabled.  I'm not quite sure why the string notation doesn't work, as opposed to:

```
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
```

But this solved the problem.